# OBS WebRTC data channel not connecting

Tags: webrtc, rtcdatachannel, obs

I have a project that requires a WebRTC data channel to work in OBS. It works great on Windows but won't connect on Mac.

An easy way to test it is to open up this page in a browser that supports webRTC: https://mdn-samples.mozilla.org/s/webrtc-simple-datachannel/
You should be able to connect, type a message and send and receive it.
In OBS if you add a browser with the address and try to do the same it doesn't work.

No errors show up in the console when debugging but what is interesting is these logs show up in terminal:

[0516/215229.218359:ERROR:data_channel.cc(44)] Accepting maxRetransmits = -1 for backwards compatibility
[0516/215229.218421:ERROR:data_channel.cc(49)] Accepting maxRetransmitTime = -1 for backwards compatibility

Any help would be appreciated.